# US visa previously denied. How do I explain this on a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am applying for a UK short stay visa (tourist visa). In the personal details and travel history. I wrote that I was denied a US visa and the reason why (no strong social / economic ties to my home country). Do I need to provide them a copy of paper that the US embassy provided why I was denied?

Comment: No, a reference number and the stated refusal code would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @HankyPanky:

> No, a reference number and the stated refusal code would be just fine.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers  I got my visa approved already 

Comment: @Czarstar in this case please consider accepting my answer :)